# Formatting issue for print function

Tags: python

Having problem with getting my code to print lists how I want them to.

```
while index < len(choice_counts):
print(choice_titles[index]);
for number in range(0,choice_counts[index]):
    print ("*", end=" ",)
index = index + 1
```

The current output is looking like:

```
Steal
* * * * * * * Deal
* * * Comp steal
* * * * * * * * * * comp deal
```

Whilst I'm trying to get it like

```
Steal * * * * * * * 
Deal * * *
Comp steal * * * * * * * * * * 
Comp deal
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and 1) indent the Python code correctly, 2) *do not indent* lines that are *not* code, input, or output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

```
choice_counts = [3,6,10]
choice_titles = ['a','b','c']
for idx, title in enumerate(choice_titles):
    print title, "*" * choice_counts[idx]
```

Output

```
a ***
b ******
c **********
```